# How can I print this?

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself python using interactivepython.org. I have come across a problem that I can not figure out. I have the slope and the spacing correct. I need it to print one less number every time. Could anybody help a newbie out?...

The code I have written:

```
numLines = 10

for i in range(numLines):

    for k in range(i):
        print(' ', end = ' ')

    for j in range(1, numLines):
        print(j, end = ' ')

    print()

    print(" ")
```

Prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

              1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

                1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Want to Print:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

      0 1 2 3 4 5 6

        0 1 2 3 4 5

          0 1 2 3 4

            0 1 2 3

              0 1 2

                0 1

                  0
```

Comment: All of the answers below seem to work great! Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, The above answers are perfectly fine. But this is my way of doing things... :)

Code:

```
l = map(str,range(0,10))
for i in range(10):
    print ' '.join(l[:len(l)-i]).rjust(20)
```

Output:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6
         0 1 2 3 4 5
           0 1 2 3 4
             0 1 2 3
               0 1 2
                 0 1
                   0
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes Burhan Khalid. But my gut feels comfortable with rjust than the one you mentioned. Anyways thanks for letting him know one more way to do things :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numLines = 10

for i in range(numLines, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, numLines - i):
        print " ",
    for k in range(0, i):
        print k,
    print
```

Comment: Oh cool I didn't realize you could use range to count backwards. Just curious though...why is my solution wrong? does it go against some best practice? Please let me know as I want to be better! Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I think your "spaces" for is working fine, but the problem is in the second nested for, where you are printing all the numbers from 1 to numberLines.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
numLines = 10
for i in range(numLines):
    print "".join ("  " for j in range(i)) + " ".join (str(j) for j in range(numLines - i))
```

**Output**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```

Comment: This is a bit over my head currently. Thank you for the answer however!! Looks efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out. I had to decrement numLines by one inside the first for loop.

Comment: Wrong answer. It works, but it's not the natural solution to the problem.